# Writing $\frac{1}{x+5}$ as $\frac{A}{x}+\frac{B}{5}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is this possible? (in this case specifically, but also in general for any fraction with addition/subtraction in the denominator).

I thought this would be easy, but upon trying it and thinking some more

- theres 2 unknowns and one equation, so we probably can't identify a unique $A$ and $B$?

For example, I feel like the simplest manipulation is to multiple both sides by $5$ and move the $A$ term over, which gives
$$
B=\frac{5}{x+5} - \frac{5A}{x} =_{A=1} \frac{-25}{x(x+5)}
$$
which is not the same as if we assumed $A=2$

Comment: It will be a infinite series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$\frac{A}{x}+\frac{B}{5}=\frac{5A+Bx}{5x}=\frac{1}{x+5}\implies 5Ax+25A+Bx^2+5Bx=5x$$

then for $B=0$

$$5Ax+25A=5x \implies A=\frac{x}{x+5}$$

and for $A=0$

$$Bx^2+5Bx=5x\implies B=\frac{5}{x+5}$$

which are trivial solutions and then it is not possible obtain the equality for $A,B$ constants.

Comment: Im not sure that $\implies B=0$ (unless we require $B$ to be a constant) but okay. (for example we could instead have $A=0$ and $B=\frac{5}{x+5}$, given some domain restriction).

Comment: Yes you are right, it should be correct consider the 2 cases.

Answer (score 3):

You can't because
$\dfrac1{x+5}$
diverges as
$x \to  -5$
and the right side
doesn't.

Comment: But we could have either $A$ or $B$ diverge as $x\to -5$? I.e. $A=1$ and $B = \frac{-5}{x(x+5)}$? (if we allow $A,B$ to not be constants, in which case poor notation on my part).

Comment: @user106860: If you allow $A$ and $B$ to be any functions, then the whole question becomes silly, since you can take for example $A=0$ and $B=5/(x+5)$.